# is it possible to convert the DB2 Db to Derby Db ?

Tags: db2, derby

I have DB2 Db and want to conver the data and schema to derby how i can do that ? 
I want to convert the Db2 commends to derby Db command.
is there any simple way i can do this

Comment: A fair bit of the base table creation scripts will simply run on Derby (SQL is a standard language), so the simple thing to do is just run the scripts and adjust what throws errors.  Most queries and statements will also run just fine, so again just try running stuff and corrects what has issues.  A good set of test data and programs will stand you and good stead.  There are supposedly tools that can retarget things like table-creation scripts, but I've never used them and don't know what they are.  What _specific_ problems are you having?

Comment: One tool for schema conversion is DdlUtils: https://db.apache.org/ddlutils/